# Addition of number string in javascript with leading zeros

Tags: javascript, html, regex, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Following is my code, which is working fine in most scenarios except in case of leading Zeros. It should preserve trailing zeros like -`001 + 1 = 002`

Code -

```js
function incrementString (str) {
  if(str === '') return "1";
  
  if(!str.slice(-1).match(/\d/)) return `${str}1`;
  
  const replacer = x => {
    // Check if number 
    return (parseInt(x) + 1).toString();
  }
  
  return str.replace(/\d+/g, replacer )
}

// Return foobar2 which is correct
console.log(incrementString("foobar1"))

// Return foobar100 which is correct
console.log(incrementString("foobar099"))

// Return foobar2 which is incorrect, is should be foobar002
console.log(incrementString("foobar001"))

// Return foobar1 which is incorrect, is should be foobar001
console.log(incrementString("foobar000"))

// Return foobar101 which is incorrect, is should be foobar0101
console.log(incrementString("foobar0100"))
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use this regex soluton:

```js
function incrementString (str) {
  if(str === '') return "1";
  
  if(!str.slice(-1).match(/\d/)) return `${str}1`;
  
  const replacer = (m, g1, g2) => {
    // Check if number 
    var nn = (g1?g1:"") + (parseInt(g2) + 1).toString()
    return nn.slice(-1 * m.length)

  }
  
  return str.replace(/(0*)(\d+)/g, replacer )
}

// Return foobar2
console.log(incrementString("foobar1"))

// Return foobar100
console.log(incrementString("foobar099"))

// Return foobar002
console.log(incrementString("foobar001"))

// Return foobar001
console.log(incrementString("foobar000"))

// Return foobar0101
console.log(incrementString("foobar0100"))

// Return foobar01000
console.log(incrementString("foobar00999"))

// Return foobar010
console.log(incrementString("foobar009"))
```

Comment: Thx a lot for `/(0*)(\d+)/`... I missed this part by miles .. I was thinking to do a search in replacer method itself but this one is really cool :)

Comment: This is wrong btw - incrementString("foobar099") it is making 0100

Comment: `foobar0100` becomes `foobar0101`, `foobar0999` becomes `foobar1000` means 0 should preserve till the time the following number not exceeding the limit in which its incrementing -> `foobar0000100` becomes `foobar0000101` & `foobar0000999` becomes `foobar0001000`

Comment: I hope I provided u a reasonable explanation..honestly I was thinking of no zeros but to increment but that is the problem statement :(

Comment: `Expected: 'foobar01000', instead got: 'foobar001000'`, `Expected: '010', instead got: '0010'`

Answer (score 1):

Everything seems to be perfect, you need to only handle the regex part of the leading zeroes in your `replacer` function.Below is the updated code for the same.

```
function incrementString(str) {
  if (str === '')
    return "1";

  if (!str.slice(-1).match(/\d/)) {
    return `${str}1`;
  }

  const replacer = x => {
    var leadingZerosMatched = x.match(/^0+/);
    var incrementedNumber = (parseInt(x) + 1).toString();
    var leadingZeroes;
    if (leadingZerosMatched && incrementedNumber.length < x.length) {
      leadingZeroes = leadingZerosMatched[0];
      if(leadingZeroes.length === x.length) {
        leadingZeroes = leadingZeroes.slice(0, leadingZeroes.length-1)
      }
    }
    return leadingZeroes ? leadingZeroes + incrementedNumber : incrementedNumber;
  }
  return str.replace(/\d+/g, replacer)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function incrementString (str) {
  let [
    openingPartial,
    terminatingInt
  ] = str.split(/(\d*)$/);

  if (terminatingInt) {
    const incrementedInt = String(parseInt(terminatingInt, 10) + 1);
    const leadingZeroCount = (terminatingInt.length - incrementedInt.length);

    if (leadingZeroCount >= 1) {

      terminatingInt = Array(leadingZeroCount).fill("0").concat(incrementedInt).join('');
    } else {
      terminatingInt = incrementedInt;
    }
  } else {
    terminatingInt = '1';
  }
  return `${ (openingPartial || '') }${ terminatingInt }`;
}

// Should return 'foo_003_bar1'.
console.log(incrementString("foo_003_bar"));

// Should return 'foo_003_bar_01'.
console.log(incrementString("foo_003_bar_00"));

// Should return 'foobar1'.
console.log(incrementString("foobar"));

// Should return 'foobar2'.
console.log(incrementString("foobar1"));

// Should return 'foobar100'.
console.log(incrementString("foobar099"));

// Should return 'foobar002'.
console.log(incrementString("foobar001"));

// Should return 'foobar001'.
console.log(incrementString("foobar000"));

// Should return 'foobar0101'.
console.log(incrementString("foobar0100"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could split your string from digits and use `padStart` after increment to preserve leading `0`:

```js
const incrementString = (str) => {
  const [chars, nums] = str.split(/(\d+)/)

  return [
    ...chars, 
    String(Number(nums) + 1)
    .padStart(nums.length, '0')
  ].join('')
}

console.log(incrementString("foobar1"))

console.log(incrementString("foobar099"))

console.log(incrementString("foobar001"))

console.log(incrementString("foobar000"))

console.log(incrementString("foobar0100"))
```